# How to write the Apache rewrite rule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I have URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/d/tag.php?n=1&tag=php
http://example.com/d/tag.php?n=1&tag=cms
```

I want to add the rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file.to make the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/tag/1/php
```

How to write such rule?

Answer (score 3):

Here you gou:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^tag/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ tag.php?n=$1&tag=$2
```

Don't forget to put that in your `.htaccess` file under your direcrory (`d`).

Answer (score 0):

have a look to [this link](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)

mod_rewrite redirect all the requests linke http://exmple.com/d/tag.php?n=1&tag=php to a specific page there you have to write the code that handle the request

Hope this helps